# mSocket.connect(...) = java.io.Exception fcntl failed EBADF

Tags: java, android, сокет

Всем доброго времени суток. Есть приложение с `Service`ом. В нём следующий код, устанавливающий соединение с сервером:

```
private Socket mSocket = new Socket();
...
this.mSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(this.ipAddress, 81), 60000);
```

Разумеется, он лежит в отдельном потоке, IP-адрес указан верно и так далее, то бишь имею ввиду, что глупых ошибок не допускал. Но в строке `this.mSocket.connect(...)` вылетает исключение:

> java.net.SocketException: java.io.IOException: fcntl failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
>     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:120)
>     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
>     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
>     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:851)
>     at com.myPackage.I3$i2.run(I3.java:260)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
>
> Caused by: java.io.IOException: fcntl failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
>     at libcore.io.IoBridge.IsBlocking(IoBridge.java:133)
>     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:142)
>     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
>     ... 5 more
>
> Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: fcntl failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
>     at libcore.io.Posix.fcntlVoid(Native Method)
>     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.fcntlVoid(ForwardingOs.java:46)
>     at libcore.io.IoBridge.IsBlocking(IoBridge.java:126)
>     ... 7 more

Вот список всех прав приложения в `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Помогите исправить ошибку. Не знаю в чём дело.

Answer (score 0):

Интернет был по сим-карте, а передача данных отключена. Вот и не работало. Всем спасибо за помощь.